# Excel VBA - Like function does not evaluate to true

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck at VBA Like function "not functioning" properly.

Here is my simple Excel table:

[image: Just 3 columns of data]

Earlier in my code I'm getting the row count and assigning it to the byteRowCount variable, Account Name column index to the byteAcctColNum variable. Then, I iterate over the Account Name column and search for the row where the Account Name is "Customer 1" and the Product contains the string "Information" with the following code:

```
For i = 2 To byteRowCount
    
If sh.Cells(i, byteAcctColNum) = "Customer 1" And (CStr(sh.Cells(i, byteProdColNum).Value) Like "*Information*") Then
        boolCust1InfCases = True
End If
```

The challenge is, the (CStr(sh.Cells(i, byteProdColNum).Value) never evaluates to True (I Step Into and check in the Immediate Window.)

Any ideas on why this is not working?

Thanks!

Comment: I see no reason it wouldn't work, assuming the code is looking at the correct columns and 
 row and that the Account Name is **exactly** "Customer 1" (case-sensitive, and no leading/trailing spaces or other invisible characters).

Comment: Tri `Instr` instead; `And Instr(1, Cells(i, byteProdColNum), "Information") > 0`

Comment: I verified the rows and columns and the values from the Watch Window. The main thing here is the part that comes after the And statement. "Like" never finds the string "*Information*" or "*nformation*". That's where I'm stuck at.

Comment: @Absinthe Many thanks! Without understanding why or how it works while "Like" doesn't, your solution worked. Can you please change your comment to reply so that I can upvote it and mark as an answer?